# SQL issue on query. need a better/alternate query

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Say we have a table T

```
+------+
| NUMM |
+------+
|   1  |
|   5  |
|   3  |
|   8  |
+------+
```

I want the nearest bigger number from the column numm to be in column numm1.
The result will look like this

```
+-------------+
| NUMM | NUMM1|
+-------------+
|   1  |   3  |
|   3  |   5  |
|   5  |   8  |
+-------------+
```

I wrote a query like this and it works. But i would like to know if there is a better way for sollution.

```
select numm, numm + min(dif) as numm1
  from (select distinct a.numm numm, b.numm numm1, b.numm - a.numm dif
         from (select *
              from T
             where numm != (select max(numm) from T )) a
      join T b
        on 1 = 1)
where dif > 0
group by numm
```

Comment: What if you have 5 rows?

Comment: It's not 100% clear what result you expect - do you want the successor for each number?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name with my query it works  with any number of rows.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt I want the nearest bigger number from the column numm to be in column numm1. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes, it's clear. Please add this information to your question (by using the "Edit" button).

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Thank you, it's done

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the direct successor, you can use the `lead()` windowing function:

```
select * from (
  select 
    numm, 
    lead(numm) over (order by numm) as numm1 
  from t  
) 
where numm1 is not null
order by numm;
```

Comment: Comparing to my solution and another answer here, this one seems to be the fastest way
Thanks

Comment: This seems to be a correct query but, if your records are repeated than the above query will fail. To handle repeated records refer to my solution below. I hope that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If it's oracle, you can use row_number() function to rank, then inner join with [left_table].rank = [right_table].rank - 1:

```
SELECT a.numm,
       b.numm
FROM
  (SELECT numm, row_number() over(order by numm) AS rank FROM pn_test) a
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT numm, row_number() over(order by numm) AS rank FROM pn_test) b
ON a.rank = b.rank - 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below query if you have repeated records in your table:

```
WITH CTE_ABC
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT NUMM
    FROM [Table]
    )
    ,CTE_XYZ
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT NUMM
            ,lead(NUMM) OVER (
                ORDER BY NUMM
                ) AS numm1
        FROM CTE_ABC
        ) A
    WHERE numm1 IS NOT NULL
    )
SELECT A.NUMM
    ,B.numm1
FROM [Table] A
LEFT JOIN CTE_XYZ B
    ON A.columnId = B.columnId
WHERE B.numm1 IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Frank's answer is probably the best when there are no duplicate numbers, but if you can end up with duplicates here's one possible solution:

```
with t1 as (
 select numm
      , dense_rank() over (order by numm) rnk
   from t
)
select t1.numm
     , t2.numm numm1
  from t1
  join (select distinct numm, rnk-1 rnk from t1) t2
    on t1.rnk = t2.rnk;
```

In this solution the `DENSE_RANK` analytic function is first used in T1 to give every distinct `NUMM` a sequential number (RNK).  In the second stage T1 is join on RNK to the distinct set of numm and rnk-1 values from t1.

Looking for better performance, this might do the job:

```
with t1 as (
 select numm
      , dense_rank() over (order by numm) rnk
      , row_number() over (partition by numm order by rownum) ord
   from t
)
select t1.numm
     , t2.numm numm1
  from t1
  join t1 t2
    on t1.rnk = t2.rnk-1
   and t2.ord = 1;
```

Here I added a way to grab one record for each numm to the subfactored query and eliminated the distinct operation in T2.  With a limited data set of just 5 records and no indexes it has a cost of 9 vs a cost of 10 for the prior query.

Comment: A bit expensive but, yes, this covers all the situations and the query is easy to understand. Thank you

Comment: With the limited dataset provided the cost difference between my original query and the one I just added are pretty negligible.